# Javascript: Rotating a Circle in 3D

Tags: javascript

I have a circle I have drawn onto a canvas in HTML.

I want to rotate this around the x-axis into the z-axis. Ultimately I would then like to repeat this at a given rate to create the illusion of a sphere. Then repeat around the y-axis.

Finally, I want to do so for an ellipse to create a spheroid.

However, I am unsure of the first steps; the rotation in the z-axis around the x-axis.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("circleCanvas");
var mC = canvas.getContext("2d");
mC.beginPath();
mC.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
mC.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="circleCanvas" width="300" height="150">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Comment: You probably have to project a circle in 3D space onto a plane. I advise you to google it to get more examples. This is what I found that may help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388747/formula-for-ellipse-formed-from-projecting-a-tilted-circle-onto-the-xy-plane. However, this topic is much deeper. For example, the isometric camera will give a different result than perspective. You could simulate it using just ellipse, but it looks wrong (https://codepen.io/SciFiThief/pen/MWYGPoZ). You could look for some libraries, so you don't have to implement it yourself unless you want to.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I fear this might be overly complex and there is a quicker/better approach elsewhere.